# Is it safe to use MG Chemicals Nickel Conductive Pen on a surface exposed to hand/skin touch?

Tags: circuit-design, electrically-conductive

I'm currently working on a project i.e. making a custom controller for my own game. I've to make a glove like controller. I'm currently using wires for making the controller work but I've listened to this new conductive pen thing (I thought it would be better if I get rid of wires on glove controller for a better experience) and I ordered one (MG Chemicals 841AR-P Nickel Conductive Pen). This conductive pen has a lot of warnings and danger signs which state it can cause skin cancer or eye irritations etc. I want to know that does it cause any problem when the ink is dried (or these are just the dangers when ink is not dried yet) as I've to use it on the glove-like controller which will be in direct contact with skin.

Did anyone use Nickel based conductive pen on bare surfaces?

Comment: Would be useful if you could provide a link to / read the 'MSDS' information.

If you provide this I, or a fellow member can probably advise you, although from your question It would seem clear you may have already read this information, certainly doesn't look good from what you have said anyway. But link us the information too, or better yet, possibly for a more definitive answer, email the manufacturer too.

Comment: Some people are allergic to nickel specifically, which would be an issue, the other issue is what other chemicals are in there and what nickel 'compounds' may be present / produced, as although nickel metal is generally quite benign to most people, nickel compounds can be very nasty indeed. There may be an issue with particle sizes too and potential ingestion following wear of said gloves. I don't want to scare you but it certainly is a subject worth more thought for you on this, or any project people decide to pursue. All the best.

Comment: @Rendeverance thank you for the reply. The ink contains Nickel and Acetone (written on the box of the pen). There is no more information on the box about any other compounds etc. 
Here is the [link](https://www.mgchemicals.com/products/prototyping-and-circuit-repair/conductive-pens/841ar-p-nickel-conductive-pen) the product site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the extra information, I can see from the MSDS you linked that the solution seems to be nickel micro particulate suspended in a mix of volatiles; the acetone you mentioned, dimethyl carbonate, amyl methyl ketone & propylene glycol monomethyl ether acetate.

As you mentioned, it would be ill advised to get this on you when wet, and you will need to try and avoid that in your construction.

As for use of the dried product, there may be some limited residues in there, but the nickel is the main component as you have mentioned.

.

I have a few concerns for this if you are intending using it for a product for other people to use:

1) Nickel is a known allergen to a number of people whom are sensitive to it (As alluded to in my comment) - so will not be suitable for all users.

2) As the nickel is dispersed as a suspension of particles, these particles may, or may not (Read:probably not), bond well to your substrate (the glove). This is a definite issue, especially with respect to a product seeing movement and abrasion, as these particles will be released, so will fall from the glove over time (contaminating the user and area with nickel particles and degrading performance over time). Since we have no data on the particulate size, there is a chance they could be inhaled, which is a potential health issue.

3) Related to point 2 - many metals possess some different properties and even increased toxicities when in particulate form, especially where inhaled. (Just to be aware of)

4) the nickel particles may change over time and react with things the gloves come into contact with (including the users skin) to form nickel compounds. Many nickel compounds and to be fair even nickel itself, is/are classified as carcinogens, and some are really bad.

.

I could go on but essentially, it may work, but I would suggest that UNLESS its just a prototype and you are taking precautions like washing hands after use and not abusing the glove, its probably a bad idea.
Another thing to note is that nickel does not possess great conductivity.

Silver would be a better choice IMO, but without seeing a product you intend to use its hard to say, and I would also say that using conductive pens is unlikely to result in a durable product. My suggestion would be to look at conductive thread / fabric, and weave the conductive thread through the glove fabric.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Rendeverance. From your answer and an answer above I've started to think that it is not even a good idea to use a conductive pen on such a flexible and skin exposed surface (the glove). The conductive fabric just seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer for the risks of the dried product does not appear to be possible with any degree of certainty. The [datasheet](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/3e96011d726311fb3b78e268cb3a25c0.pdf) and [SDS](https://www.sra-shops.com/docs/srasolder/sds/sds-841ar-p.pdf) only cover the risks of the liquid state. It seems safe to assume that some irritation is possible and any nickel allergy risks are still in play. Overall, probably not a good idea.

That's all going to be somewhat besides the point if you want your product to not only be safe but also *actually work* reliably.

The documents make clear that adhesion is not reliable on oily surfaces, which will become an issue with skin contact. Also, based on my somewhat limited experience playing with similar products, they are not very resilient to repeated flexing or friction. Even if it were safe, it wouldn't last long in a glove type product.

Fortunately, flat flexible conductors are dirt cheap and readily available from most major component distributors in a variety of lengths, conductor counts, and pin pitches. Might be worth looking into [something like this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/FSP-22A-2/A129257-ND/5591553) instead. [Conductive fabric](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1168?gclid=Cj0KCQjw8MvWBRC8ARIsAOFSVBWt9D-TyF7gHmuHOM5JHycKJisVgS4X03f1E5pbvp6JHR1c4Q9KpRoaAngjEALw_wcB) might also be a solution, albeit with some additional complications of insulation and moisture protection.

Comment: thank you for your time. I'll use conductive threads in the glove controller as it seems safer to use them.